# Sequences bounding each other implies convergence?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $a_n$ and $b_n$ are real-valued sequences, and there exists constants $c_1, c_2$ such that

$$c_1a_n \leq b_n \leq c_2a_n$$

Certainly $a_n$ converges if and only if $b_n$ converges, but does $a_n - b_n$ necessarily converge?

Comment: Both implications in the statement after "Certainly" are false, see $a_n=3+\sin (n\pi/2)$, $b_n=3-2^{-n}$, $c_2=9$, $c_1=\frac19$ and the same with $(a_n,b_n)$ and $(c_1,c_2)$ swapped.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that sequences are bounded is not enough, the simplest example is to take one sequence constant, e.g. $(a_n)_n=(1,1,1,1,1,\cdots)$ for instance and another which oscillate e.g. $(b_n)_n=(1,2,1,2,1,2,\cdots)$

It is immediate that $a_n\le b_n\le 2a_n\quad$ yet $a_n$ converge but not $b_n$.

Same for the other implication $\frac 12 b_n\le a_n\le b_n\quad$ convergence of $b_n$ is false.

Of course it goes for the difference too, as $(a_n-b_n)_n=(0,-1,0,-1,0,-1,\cdots)$ does not converge either.

On the other hand if you assume that both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are convergent then $a_n-b_n\to\lim a_n-\lim b_n$ is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

No. Just take $a_n = 2n$ and $b_n = n$.

Comment: What if we constrained ourselves to $c_1, c_2 > 0$?

Comment: $c_1, c_2$ are positive in this case. Just take $c_2  = 1$ and $c_1 = 1/3$.